# Create an Index with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I've read the documentation on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), but it doesn't answer what I'm after.  If I create an index on specified columns using a `WHERE` clause for certain IDs, will this index include any new IDs that are inserted into the database?  Or will it only add those records with the IDs in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you're creating an index to eliminate NULL values from a column (one of the classic examples). As new values come in that are not NULL, they will be added to the index in the same way as any non-filtered index. But any new NULL values will not be added to the index because you've created it in such a way as to filter out NULL values. Any other filters you apply will work exactly the same way, including or excluding values as they get added/updated based on the criteria of the WHERE clause defined within the index.

Answer (score 0):

The where clause on an index works the same way it would in a query so if your index has X = 'ABC' then that is all the index will cover.